# HTML with inline JavaScript Served from WCF service as Stream getting partially duplicated

Tags: wcf, stream

I have a WCF operations that opens an html file on disc and sends that back to the client (browser). The method looks like this:

```
public Stream Home()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Page requested");

    // Open the stream and read it back.
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"index.html", FileMode.Open))
    {
        string page = "";
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
        while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
        {
            page += temp.GetString(b);
        }
        byte[] result = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(page);
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
        Console.Write(result);
        return new MemoryStream(result);
    }
}
```

This works fine with a vanilla JS XMLHttpRequest, but when I add the jQuery CDN reference, the HTML seems to get loaded twice.

Why is this?

index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    // setTimeout(function() {
    //     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //     if ('withCredentials' in request) {
    //         request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //             if (request.readyState === 4) {
    //                 if (request.status === 200) {
    //                     document.getElementById('ajaxContent').innerHTML = request.responseText;

    //                 } else {
    //                     alert('An error has occurred');
    //                 }
    //             }
    //         };
    //         request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:xx/WebService/JsTest', true);
    //         request.send(null);
    //     }

    // }, 2000)

        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('hi');
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div id="ajaxContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The resultant page (with my javascript commented out) looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    // setTimeout(function() {
    //     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //     if ('withCredentials' in request) {
    //         request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //             if (request.readyState === 4) {
    //                 if (request.status === 200) {
    //                     document.getElementById('ajaxContent').innerHTML = request.responseText;

    //                 } else {
    //                     alert('An error has occurred');
    //                 }
    //             }
    //         };
    //         request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:xx/WebService/JsTest', true);
    //         request.send(null);
    //     }

    // }, 2000)

        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('hi');
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div id="ajaxContent"></div>




</body>



</html>
UStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    // setTimeout(function() {
    //     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //     if ('withCredentials' in request) {
    //         request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //             if (request.readyState === 4) {
    //                 if (request.status === 200) {
    //                     document.getElementById('ajaxContent').innerHTML = request.responseText;

    //                 } else {
    //                     alert('An error has occurred');
    //                 }
    //             }
    //         };
    //         request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:xx/WebService/JsTest', true);
    //         request.send(null);
    //     }

    // }, 2000)

        $(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. Are you using that commented out code to load the HTML file from WCF?

Comment: nope. I have an index.html file, the method loads that file and returns it to the browser as a Stream. Then, for whatever reason, the bottom HTML code is what results when the jquery has loaded. 

My javascript is commented out, it shouldn't be running

Comment: But when I remove my commented out javascript everything works fine

Comment: So... you're using WCF as a web server? I mean, you could just return the `FileStream` rather than reading as `byte`s, copying those into a `string`, then getting the `byte`s out of the `string` and finally pushing that into a `MemoryStream`...